# Microchip XC32 no warning with "illegal cast"

Tags: casting, warnings, microchip

I have a function that should return the SysTick variable:

```
uint32_t TickGet(void){
    return SysTick;
}
```

However SysTick is defined as an int:

```
int SysTick;
```

For some reason, the XC32 compiler is perfectly happy with this arrangement. No warnings warnings whatsoever are thrown. Not even with -Wall as a XC32-GCC option.

Does anyone know how to get the XC32 compiler to list this warning?

*edit*, ofcourse I want the SysTick variable to be defined as an uint32_t. That's besides the point, my problem is with the compiler not throwing warnings for such occasions.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this in XC32 1.40. I'm with you, would also be interested to know why this doesn't throw a warning, because it definitely feels like it should warn you about implicit unsigned/signed conversion.

Maybe try opening a ticket w/ microchip support if you have no luck with an answer here.  Or try the community support forum, as it's pretty active.